# Amazon weight returned wrong

Tags: amazon-product-api

Given the following product
[http://www.amazon.com/Nike-377780-Legend-Dri-Fit-Sleeve/dp/B00IT7QJCE/ref=sr_1_2?s=apparel&ie=UTF8&qid=1419252102&sr=1-2&keywords=nike](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IT7QJCE)

Notice the shipping weight being 4 pounds with 7 x 7 x 1 measurements,
This is what I'm getting from amazon :

```
[ItemDimensions] => Array
    (
        [Height] => 100
        [Length] => 700
        [Weight] => 0
        [Width] => 700
    )

[PackageDimensions] => Array
    (
        [Height] => 300
        [Length] => 1200
        [Weight] => 50
        [Width] => 1000
    )
```

Notice the item dimensions are 0 and the Package has a weight of 50.
Now comes the question, 50 what? Everything comes from amazon in 100th of a unit, so 700 is 100th of an inch, which is 7 inches. THe weight however, would turn to 0.5 pounds, which is obviously not 4.

Has anyone encountered anything similar ? There are a few SO questions that relate to the matter, none with any solid answer(or an answer at all at times)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Sorry buddy, we neglected the project midway, we could never answer this question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got there in the end. The measures are 100s of an inch. The weights are 100s of a pound. But you got your arithmetic wrong on the weights. To turn both sets of data into meaningful units weights and measures that correspond to the way they are listed on Amazon you would do something like:

```
 $productWeight =  16 / 100 * $ItemAttributes->ItemDimensions->Weight;
 $shippingWeight = 16 / 100 * $ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Weight;
```

for LHW in inches:

```
$length =  round($ItemAttributes->ItemDimensions->Length / 100,1);
```

or if you want centimeters: / 100 * 2.54,1);

```
 $length =  round($ItemAttributes->ItemDimensions->Length / 100 * 2.54,1);
```

All of the dimensions have both an ItemDimensions version and a PackageDimensions version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, Good effort! I've also read it's 100th of a pound, however the math doesn't add up. On the product page it's 4 pounds. the weight of 50/100 (pounds) would result in 0.5. Also your math would result in a weight of 8(not sure which units you used)

This still bugs me at nights.

Comment: The shipping weight on your amazon page you linked at the top of your post is 8 ounces. Take a look. If it was saying 4 before I would imagine the merchant listing was wrong in some way. But right now my answer above gives the correct answer: 8 ounces.

Comment: Gah I could've swore it said 4 pounds , Your answer fits perfectly now. Thanks.